# Show upvote counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the gem file acts_as_votable. Currently, when I click the "Like" button it seems that it is working, and the flash notice says "You have liked it!" However, I would like to keep track of how many likes I have for each review. So, I added this line of code in my index.html.erb file (below) but I am getting an error stating: "Could not find table 'votes' "

```
<td><%= link_to 'Like', like_review_path(review), method: :post%>
(<%=review.get_upvotes.size%>)</td>
```

This is what I have in my reviews_controller.rb file:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]

  def upvote
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
   @review.upvote_by @current_user
   flash[:notice] = 'You liked the review!'
   redirect_to :back
  end
```

This is for my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :reviews do
   member do
    post "/like", to: "reviews#upvote"
  end
 end
```

Finally, this is what I have in my review.rb file:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: did you run the migrations after adding the gem and runing the initializer?

Comment: Yes, I did run the migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be correct on your code.

try to run the migrations, this seems to be the problem. when you run this

```
rails generate acts_as_votable:migration
```

you need to run the migrations too

```
rake db:migrate
```

check that the migrations are in the last version and if this doesn't work, restart the rails server, but if it says that could not find the table, then you just didn't runned the migrations, or they returned an error, or deleted the table manually after the migration was done. please see those cases so we can discard this options

Comment: That was helpful! I now get Like(0) to show, but doesn't update when clicking it. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Removing the '@' from @current_user was the issue.